# Image Collection minimum and maximum Extraction in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, modis, ndvi

I've wrote this code but it makes error about min and max image?

```js
var modis = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/006/MOD13Q1")
.filterBounds(geometry)
.filterDate("2000-01-01","2001-01-01")
.select("NDVI");

print(modis);

var mod13 = modis.map(function(img){
  return img.multiply(0.0001)
  .copyProperties(img,['system:time_start','system:time_end']);
});

print(mod13);

var vci = mod13.map(function(img){
 var id = img.id();
 var min =  img.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.min(),geometry,250);
 var max = img.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.max(),geometry,250);
 return img.expression(
   "(NDVI-min)/(max-min)",{
     "NDVI" : img,
     "max" : max,
     "min" : min
   }).copyProperties(img,['system:time_start','system:time_end']);
});
```

Comment: it's error message:
ImageCollection (Error)
Error in map(ID=2000_03_05):
Image.subtract, argument 'image2': Invalid type. Expected: Image<unknown bands>. Actual: Dictionary<Float>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`img.reduceRegion` returns a dictionary with the result of the reduction in each band, so you have to get the result for the band that you are interested in, which I understand is NDVI.

```js
var modis = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/006/MOD13Q1")
//.filterBounds(geometry) // no need to filter by bounds in MODIS
.filterDate("2000-01-01","2001-01-01")
.select("NDVI");

print(modis);

var mod13 = modis.map(function(img){
  return img.multiply(0.0001)
  .copyProperties(img,['system:time_start','system:time_end']);
});

print(mod13);

var vci = mod13.map(function(img){
 var id = img.id();
 var min =  img.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.min(), geometry,250).get('NDVI');
 var max = img.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.max(), geometry,250).get('NDVI');
 return img.expression(
   "(NDVI-min)/(max-min)",{
     "NDVI" : img,
     "max" : ee.Number(max),
     "min" : ee.Number(min)
   }).copyProperties(img,['system:time_start','system:time_end']);
});
print(vci)
```

Comment: thanks a lot. your code is true but .copyproperties() must replaced by .rename(id).

Comment: why is that? If you do that you'll loose the timestamp of the image, and rename the NDVI band with the ID of the image.. That is not what you have asked. I just answer your question

Comment: because when I was save its result with export.image it returned error, after that I replaced .id instead of .copyproperties(), then it resolved.